# How to hide phone number when calling

Tags: ios, phone-call

My app allows the user to make a phone call but I need to hide the number I'm calling to because it has a secret code within it. Is there any way to achieve this?

When I say "hide the number", I mean the phone number that appears in the the confirmation `UIAlertView` before calling and, if possible, in navigation bar when the call is in process.

Comment: Please post your code where you are displaying the number.

Answer (score 5):

Most definitely not. The phone number that gets passed to the OS when making the call cannot be modified or hidden from the user. (What if your app dialed 911?)

Also, how is a "secret code" passed via a telephone number?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the native phone number recognition code within a web view, or is this a custom button in your app.

In an app I've created, I have a button that the user can tap to call a phone number. This button presents a UIAlertView that I create myself (and therefore have complete control over what it says), and then in the alertView:didClickButtonAtIndex: delegate method, I do:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://5555555555"]];
```

to initiate the call.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you try to modify the way how ios Phone app works, your app might be rejected. I'm almost sure they will not happy to let your app dail a number without user's knowledge.